# Chrome battery optimisation

Tags: android, performance, google-chrome, webview, android-browser

Why chrome app does not appear into battery consumption section(in settings).
If chrome run into android system part what I have to write(probably in android manifest) to be exactly like chrome app?

Comment: What makes you say that Chrome doesn't show up under Battery? I see it in my own Battery view. Perhaps you're just not using it enough for it to be significant at this point?

Comment: I open 3 tabs and I don't see it... probably you have right... I use samsung galaxy S3

Comment: anyway if you know some tricks to optimize battery consumption will be appreciated

Comment: Sure. Making sure to use one big network request rather than many small network requests, and using the network when other things are using the network (e.g. by using the builtin syncing services) is a good way to optimize battery. Also, to avoid many small requests, prefetching data and also allowing users to configure how much to prefetch is a good strategy. Also, detecting the battery level and adjusting syncing accordingly is a good approach.

Comment: I just load simple urls(there is no big request or small requests)...on webview, can you write some code mby to better understand.Thx